# How to delete stored user names in the Logon Information Properties dropdown list

Tags: windows-xp, login, username

I'm using Windows XP.

In the "Stored User Names and Passwords" dialog box, under Properties, in the User Name drop down list, it shows a bunch of old server\usernames.

How can I edit that listing to remove old entries?

The servers are not listed in the "Stored User Names and Passwords" dialog box, 
that would be too easy.

[image]